# Node URL parsing and pathnames

Tags: node.js, url

[url.parse](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) does not seem to decode `%20`s and such in the `pathname` property. Am I expected to run the `pathname` through `decodeURIComponent` as well, or am I doing something wrong? Why doesn't `url.parse` decode it automatically?

Comment: I think that according to the link you gave, the decoded elements would appear in the ```query``` property of the object that is returned by url.parse not the ```pathname``` property. Assuming you've passed the second parameter as ```true``` to url.parse.

Comment: @ctlacko I'm not talking about query params. I'm talking about an URL like `/client/2830/Service%20Provider%20Envelope(JOE%20DIRT)%20(1).doc`. I want that last bit, the filename.

Comment: Then, yes it seems that this format is outside of the realm of what url.parse is capable of parsing. If you are able to change the last forward slash into a question mark, and also are willing to URL-encode that period before the doc, then url.parse would work. Otherwise, you may be forced to use decodeURIComponent. I wish I could provide more insight for you. I read through RFC 2396 a bit, but didn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: @ctlacko So then the correct way to get the path (without querystring) from a request object is `decodeURIComponent(url.parse(req.url).pathname)`?

Comment: Well, I can't comment on correctness, but that should work with the input you provided. I'll code up a test for you later if you're still stuck.

Comment: @ctlacko It's alright, thank you for your help. This has worked for all my test cases so far. The only case I'm uncertain about is  `xxx/yyy%2Fzzz`. Should I decode that `%2F` or not? I mean I guess I should because it's just a %-encoded character like any other, but if I do then it becomes a path separator (`/`) and suddenly my 2-part path becomes a 3-part path. Which makes me think I should split the path and *then* decode each dirname separately. I guess it really depends on how you want to use the path.